# how to display retrieved data from database using django

Tags: django

i have a django project that is connected to SQL Server  i tried to retrieve data from the database.

if i try to display all the data it run correct and display all the values.

but if i try to display the data in an **html table** it doesn't display anything.

## views.py

```
def connect(request):
    conn = pyodbc.connect(
        'Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
        'Server=DESKTOP-LPD1575\\SQLEXPRESS;'
        'Database=testDB;'
        'UID=test;'
        'PWD=test;'

    )

    cursor = conn.cursor()
    c = cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Artist')
    return render (request,'connect.html',{"c":c})
```

## connect.html

```
{% for row in c %}
    {{ row }}
{% endfor %}
```

this code in the html template  work  and display the data.

but if i try to do as below it will not work

```
<table align = "center">
        <tr align="center">
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>FolderNumber</th>
            <th>Title</th>

        </tr>
        {% for row in c %}
            <tr align="center">
                <td>{{ row.id }}</td>
                <td>{{ row.artistName }}</td>
                <td>{{ row.activeFrom }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
```

anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Each row in your result is a list, not a dict. You would need to use indexes not keys:

```
   {% for row in c %}
        <tr align="center">
            <td>{{ row.0 }}</td>
            <td>{{ row.1 }}</td>
            <td>{{ row.2 }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

or better

```
   {% for row in c %}
        <tr align="center">
            {% for item in row %}
                <td>{{ item }}</td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

However, really you should not be running SQL queries directly, but define a model for your table and access it that way.

Comment: its not possible to create model because the database is MS sql server and already its a huge predefined database.